# Hangfire Dashboard Authorization not working properly on Server

Tags: iis, amazon-ec2, hangfire

My Asp Net Core app is hosted on Amazon EC2 using IIS. I have added HangFire Authorization by implementing IDashboardAuthorizationFilter. My client application is an Angular application. From my Controller (Asp Net Core side), I am passing the Bearer Token in a cookie with Response.Redirect to Hangfire dashboard url.

On locally hosted app, it is working perfectly fine and my Authorize method in my Authorization Filter implementation passes the cookie in the request. Also, the HangFire Dashboard shows up in the browser in the same tab.

However, on prod/qa environment, there are 2 issues:

1. The original GET request sent from client to my controller API returns with status 302, and a subsequent request to hangfire url becomes a GET request instead of Redirect. It starts parsing the html (of hangfire) and throws error in dev console.
2. My HangFire Dashboard Authorize method gets the request without the cookie that I set in my controller API before redirecting to hangfire url.

Please see my code below:

```
MyAuthorizationFilter.cs

public class MyAuthorizationFilter: IDashboardAuthorizationFilter {

 public bool Authorize(DashboardContext context) {
            try {
                
                var httpContext = context.GetHttpContext();

                // If it is a request for localhost, allow it straightaway
                if (httpContext.Request.Host.ToUriComponent().Contains(Constants.Localhost)) {
                    return true;
                }

                string accessToken = httpContext.Request.Cookies[Constants.HangFireTokenKey];

                LogHelper.ApiLog("Access Token: " + accessToken, LoggerLevel.DEBUG);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken)) {

                    return false;
                }

                ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = Utils.ValidateToken(accessToken);

                LogHelper.ApiLog("Claims Principal Claims: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(claimsPrincipal.Claims), LoggerLevel.DEBUG);

                LogHelper.ApiLog("Allowed users: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this._allowedUsers));

                if (claimsPrincipal != null) {

                    string userEmail = claimsPrincipal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "email")?.Value;

                    if (this._allowedUsers.Contains(userEmail)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;
              } catch (Exception){
                LogHelper.ApiLog("HangFire Exception:" + e);
                return false;
           }
    }

MyController.cs API

[HttpGet("hangfireDashboard")]
        public void ShowHangFireDashboard() {

            try {
                string token = Request.Headers["Authorization"];

                if (null != token) {
                    // Set our Bearer token as a cookie for Dashboard redirect
                    // Hangfire sends this cookie to Authorize method of DashBoardAuthorizationFilter 
                    Response.Cookies.Append(Constants.HangFireTokenKey, token, new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Constants.HangFireCookieExpiryTimeInMinutes) });
                    Response.Redirect(this._configuration["HangFire:DashboardUrl"]);
                }
            } catch (Exception) {
                throw;
            }
        }

My Angular Client side function - GET request to my hangfireDashboard API 
    
   /**
     * Send request for HangFire Dashboard
     */
    showHangFireDashboard() {
        const apiUrl = this._apiUrl + Global.route.hangfireDashboard;
        return this._httpClient.get(apiUrl);
    }
```

Initial GET Request from my client to my server

[image: GET request from client to server my Controller]

The following should have come as Redirect and not GET Request
[image]

Preview of above request (/hangFire) that should have come as redirect and not GET

[image]

[Updated]: Dev console shows error as it has to parse the html tag that has come as response to GET request of Hangfire (that should have been a redirect in place of GET)

[image]

Comment: Can you show me the error in dev console? and you can use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to view your request process.

Comment: @samwu I have updated my question with the error that is coming in dev console. The error is actually due to parsing of HTML tags as the web page has come as response to GET request (I was hoping to get it as redirect and not GET)

Comment: Did you specify the responseType? HttpClient by default converts response to be response.json(), I think this may also cause an error in the console.